# Java version 11.0.17 (64-bit) is outside of supported range: [17+ 64-bit]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ghidra

I have installed ghidra on my ubuntu 20.04 os and when i run ghidra with this command  `./ghidraRun`this statement is popped out (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlV2a.png)
and when i specify the path i got this error
Java version 11.0.17 (64-bit) is outside of supported range: [17+ 64-bit]

I've tried all these but yet nothing is happened [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Nx7.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. What is unclear about the error message? What happened when you used Java 17? Also note that stackoverflow is about programming questions and askng about how to use a software is usually off-topic, unless it's a sw development tool.

Comment: @Robert - Ghidra is a *software reverse engineering (SRE) suite of tools* so I think it's in bounds.

Answer (score 1):

i update the java version to 17 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Install

```
 sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk openjdk-17-jre
```

You don't have to deinstall Java 11.